# Imprimir de forma consecutiva una variable con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

actualmente estoy guardando todos mis registros con un ID este ID es auto-incrementable, lo que estoy buscando hacer es que si tengo 3 registros los id serian 11,12 y 13 pero como puedo hacer para imprimirlos así:

R00011
R00012
R00013

y que la impresión del consecutivo de acuerdo al id vaya quitando ceros, ejemplo:

Si mi id es 250 entonces debe imprimir: R00250

Este seria mi index.php con la variable ID

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>No.</td>
<td><b>$producto['id']</b></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Cualquier Ayuda me podría ser de gran utilidad, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos formas (conforme las etiquetas que pusiste); sin orden de preferencia o relevancia alguno te las comento (que yo veo claro) :D :

Considerando que finalmente serán hasta 5 numeros y una letra.

**MYSQL [LPAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)**

Que tu consulta lo devuelva en ese formato por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 'R' + LPAD(ID, 5, '0') as ID [ y todo lo demas de tu consulta]
```

**PHP [str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-pad.php)**
Donde tienes `<td><b>$producto['id']</b></td>` cambiarlo a

```
<td><b>R<?=str_pad($producto['id'], 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)?></b></td>
```

Comment: hola buenas tardes, tendria que cambiar mi consulta? y luego imprimir la variable como lo indicas?

Comment: @estrada lo anterior es solo una de ellas; donde usted considere mejor realizar el cambio; si aplicas desde la consulta ya no hace cambio en el PHP, si haras el cambio en el PHP dejas sin cambio tu consulta. Solo una de las dos opciones enunciadas.

Comment: Listo me funciono perfectamente muchas gracias.

Comment: También puedes usar sprintf , en PHP tienes varios formatos de impresión, y te ayuda a completar la cadena que quieres con los 0 necesarios. Echa un vistazo a la doc oficial https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php